# MediaPipe pose estimator with multiprocessing hangs on its process function

Tags: python, events, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, mediapipe

I am currently trying to implement MediaPipe pose estimator as an independent event-based process with Python's multiprocessing library, but it hangs on the MediaPipe's `Pose.process()` function.

I input the frame with another process (readFrames). Whenever a frame is captured, it is written into a shared object and tells the MediaPipe process (MediaPipeRunner) to start working on the current image:

```
def readFrames(ns, event):
  #initialize the video capture object
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
  while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        ns.frame = frame
        event.set()
        cv2.imshow('Orijinal Frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            return -1
    else:
        return


class MediaPipeRunner(mproc.Process):

    def __init__(self, name, nsFrame, nsMediaPipe, eventWait, eventPublish):
        super(MediaPipeRunner, self).__init__()
        
        # Specify a name for the instance
        self.name = name
        
        # Input and output namespaces
        self.nsFrame = nsFrame
        self.nsMediaPipe = nsMediaPipe

        # Waiter and publisher events
        self.eventWait = eventWait
        self.eventPublish = eventPublish

        # Create a pose estimator from MediaPipe
        mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose

        # Specify pose estimator parameters (static)
        static_image_mode = True
        model_complexity = 1
        enable_segmentation = True  # DONT CHANGE
        min_detection_confidence = 0.5

        # Create a pose estimator here
        self.pose = mp_pose.Pose(
        static_image_mode=static_image_mode,
        model_complexity=model_complexity,
        enable_segmentation=enable_segmentation,
        min_detection_confidence=min_detection_confidence,
        smooth_landmarks=False,
        )

    def run(self):
        while True:
            eventFrame.wait()
            
            # This part is where it gets stuck:
            results = self.pose.process(cv2.cvtColor(self.nsFrame.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

            if not results.pose_landmarks:
                continue

            self.nsMediaPipe.segmentation = results.segmentation_mask
            eventMP.set()
```

This is how I bind the processes, namespaces and events:

```
if __name__=="__main__":

    mgr = mproc.Manager()

    nsFrame = mgr.Namespace()
    nsMP = mgr.Namespace()

    eventFrame = mproc.Event()
    eventMP = mproc.Event()

    camCap = mproc.Process(name='camCap', target=readFrames, args=(nsFrame, eventFrame, ))
    camCap.daemon=True

    mpCap = MediaPipeRunner('mpCap', nsFrame, nsMP, eventFrame, eventMP, )
    mpCap.daemon=True

    camCap.start()
    mpCap.start()

    camCap.join()
    mpCap.join()
```

Am I taking a wrong step on processes or MediaPipe is not getting along with the multiprocessing library of Python?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance :)

P.S.: I installed MediaPipe by pip and version 0.8.9.1 is present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the problem: The `process` function behaves correctly when `with` structure is used in Python (idk why):

```
    with mp_pose.Pose(
        static_image_mode=static_image_mode,
        model_complexity=model_complexity,
        enable_segmentation=enable_segmentation,
        min_detection_confidence=min_detection_confidence,
        smooth_landmarks=False,
        ) as pose:
```

Now this part works!

```
    results = self.pose.process(cv2.cvtColor(self.nsFrame.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

I hope it might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think MediaPipe models are only accessible in the thread that creates them, so a possible workaround is to create one model per thread. The overhead isn't much.

```py
model_storage = threading.local()

# ...

        if not hasattr(model_storage, 'recogniser'):
            model_storage.recogniser = mp.tasks.vision.GestureRecognizer.create_from_options(
                mp.tasks.vision.GestureRecognizerOptions(
                    base_options=mp.tasks.BaseOptions(
                        model_asset_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                                      'models',
                                                      'HandGesture')
                    )
                )
            )
        recogniser = model_storage.recogniser
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, fixed it by changing

```
results = self.pose.process(cv2.cvtColor(self.nsFrame.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

to

```
pose= self.pose
results = pose.process(cv2.cvtColor(self.nsFrame.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

Not really sure why this works, I would love to get some input if someone understands this