# Mediapipe Pose Estimator with Multiprocessing hanging with when used in a Docker container

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing, mediapipe

I am trying to run mediapipe pose estimator inference in a docker container, `multiprocessing.Process()`. My scripts are connected to a Google PubSub service, reading messages containing images and then asynchronously processing them on multiple cores.

This works perfectly when running locally on my machine, however when I try to run it in a docker container (using the official [Mediapipe Dockerfile](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/Dockerfile) with some additions to copy in my code and install requirements etc...) it hangs on the `results = pose.process()` line. Part of me is very confused as to why this might be.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71374894/mediapipe-pose-estimator-with-multiprocessing-hangs-on-its-process-function)  seems to have managed to solve this problem, but I was not able to use the solutions to fix it in mine.

This is the code (simplified):

```
    input_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    results_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    workers = [multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_process, args=(input_queue, results_queue, project_id, topic_id)) for _ in range(num_processes)]

    for w in workers:
        w.start()

    # Create the asyncio event loop
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(
            listenForMessages(subscriber, subscription_path, input_queue))
    except:
        # graceful termination
        ...
```

The `worker_process()` function is the one which contains the mediapipe inference code (along with some other image processing)

The listenForMessages function does exactly that, listens for messages then runs a callback function when it gets one:

```
async def listenForMessages(subscriber, subscription_path, input_queue):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
   
    stop_future = loop.create_future()

    print(f"Listening for messages on {subscription_path}...")

    streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(
        subscription_path,
        callback=lambda message: callback(message, input_queue))

   ... # Some more graceful termination stuff
```

The `callback()` function just does some basic string parsing on the message, and adds it to the `input_queue`, to be processed by `worker_process()`.

Mediapipe is being called in the worker process through this class:

```
class mediapipePoseInferenceSingleton:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose
        self.pose = self.mp_pose.Pose(static_image_mode=True, model_complexity=2)

    def inference(self, image):
        # Convert PIL Image to RGB numpy array
        image_np = np.array(image.convert('RGB'))
        results = self.pose.process(image_np)

        landmarkOutput = {}
        if results.pose_landmarks:
            for landmark_idx, landmark in enumerate(results.pose_landmarks.landmark):
                landmark_name = self.mp_pose.PoseLandmark(landmark_idx).name
                landmarkOutput[landmark_name] = [landmark.x, landmark.y, landmark.z]

        return landmarkOutput
```

And it hangs on the `results = self.pose.process(image_np)` line.
Again, this works perfectly on my local machine, so if anyone can give any help at all as to whats going wrong here, I'd be very grateful.

I have tried changing the way the multiprocessing is applied, through an input queue, a Pool() object which is passed through etc..., they all worked locally but not on the container.

I have also managed to get the mediapipe multiprocessing in the Docker container working in a much simpler script without the PubSub and async stuff, so it could be down to that?

Ps this is running `mediapipe==0.10.7`.

Thanks.